# Windows 2003 server on two different workgroup networks

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking

I have a windows 2003 PC set up as a standalone server on a Workgroup network - everything is working fine.

The server has a second network card is it which I wish to connect to another Workgroup network.  Is it possible for the server to be configured so it is also visible from this network?

Both networks are small and only used for development - i.e. not a production environment - so we can cut a few corners if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just assign the second NIC an IP address in the second workgroup. Nothing more needs doing. You can even (using RRAS) configure the server to route between the two workgroups if you want.

JR

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was looking in the wrong place too - there's a firewall on the server and that was screwed down fully on the second card - all I needed was to know I was heading in the right direction to find that.

Answer (score 1):

Previous posters are correct in that you can multihome the server and it will be visible by IP address on both networks.  However, it is not possible to configure a server to belong to two different workgroups.  So any Windows functionality that relies on the server being a member of the same workgroup as the client (like browsing for shares), will be not work correctly for the second workgroup.  As previously mentioned you can mount the shares manually using the net command, or even get to them in windows explorer by typing the \ or \ into the run menu and things should be ok, although you may run into some strange permissions problems.

Comment: I suspected as much, but if you name the second workgroup to have an identical name to the first everything works without a hitch. Yes I know this sounds on odd configuration but it's the result of handling development for several different clients/tasks

Comment: That would make them in some strange sense actually part of the same workgroup, but sure it works.  The danger is that someone who is not an administrator could plug a computer into a different port and get access to the other computers.  Just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can see both worgroups, but:

It is not nessecary to be in both workgroups. You simply map the sahres from the 2nd workgroups with the command net share x: \win2k3\share /user:win2k3_local_acccount